# Installing python kernel in a Conda environment

Tags: python, kernel, ipython, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have just started using jupyter notebook for my development process. I started by creating a new python environment:

```
$ conda create -n testenv
```

Then I activate it:

```
$ source activate testenv
```

And install python kernel module:

```
$ pip install ipykernel
```

Now that's when the fuzziness begins. I want to create a new kernel specifically to my active environment only. Following documentation, I did:

```
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name testenv --display-name "Python (testenv)"
```

With this I believe I have just created a new Python kernel for the *testenv* environment to be used within Jupyter Notebook. Now, I want to confirm this information and I check:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
testenv   /home/{{user}}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/testenv
python2   /home/{{user}}/miniconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/python2

$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base         /home/{{user}}/miniconda2
testenv   *  /home/{{user}}/miniconda2/envs/testenv
```

I was expecting to see my kernel installed within the *testenv* environment, something like:

```
/home/{{user}}/miniconda2/envs/testenv/kernels/testenv
```

I am failing to see how do the environments and kernels tie together and how can I confirm this information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you create the empty environment, it installs absolutely no packages, even pip and Python. Therefore, when you use pip to install `ipykernel`, you're using the pip from the base environment. You need to create the environment with `pip` and `python`

```
conda create -n testenv python
```

You can check this by typing

```
which pip
```

after you create the blank environment.

Finally, you should use `conda` to install all packages, including ipykernel, if at all possible.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your suggestion. I have just tried it: `conda create -n testenv python ipykernel`. Now I do have a python and pip command within the *testenv* environment. However, in the end I still have my kernel located in the same old place, at `/home/{{user}}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/testenv`. I still don't get how is this kernel related to the environment I have just created, which is the central point of the question.

Comment: Did you delete that file from your previous attempts before trying this one?

Comment: Yes I cleaned environment with `$ conda env remove -n testenv` and hard-removed the testenv from the kernels folder

Comment: Then I don't know why that file gets put back, it does not happen on my Mac

Comment: May I know what would be your kernel's path then?

Comment: `/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/thermohw/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

Comment: That is really what I was expecting and did not get it :(

Comment: if you have figured out, can you please post it here? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use the following:

```
conda create -n testenv
```

After you should use:

```
conda activate testenv
conda install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name condaenv --display-name "Python3 (testenv)"
```

Once you have done this, you could start up the notebook by using `jupyter notebook` and opens any `.ipynb` notebook. Inside that notebook, select the menu Kernel > Change kernel > Python3 (condaenv) to activate the conda environment kernel.

Comment: As of 2022, when using conda, the `python3 -m ipykernel install...` step is not  required. Any conda environment that has `nb_conda_kernels` installed will find any conda environment that has `ipykernel` installed. If you are not using conda with `nb_conda_kernels` then you will need to follow the `python3 -m ipykernel install...` step

Answer (score 0):

Do what you did, but in the kernel installation step, replace `--user` with `--sys-prefix`, that is:

```
python -m ipykernel install --sys-prefix --name testenv --display-name "Python (testenv)"
```

then the kernel would be installed in the path you intended to:

```
/home/{{user}}/miniconda2/envs/testenv/kernels/testenv
```